# How to customize the theme of Mapbox

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapbox

Just starting out with Mapbox. I found the code for Objective-c but I don't know how to do it in Swift. Any ideas?

Here is the Objective-C code:

```
#import "Mapbox.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) RMMapView *mapView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[RMConfiguration sharedInstance] setAccessToken:@"<access token>"];
     // Specially this line below
    RMMapboxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"mapbox.wheatpaste"];

    // set coordinates
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.910003, -77.015533);
    self.mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                                      andTilesource:tileSource]; 
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
}
@end
```

Here is my Swift code

```
import MapboxGL
class AppViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
   var mapView: MGLMapView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       mapView = MGLMapView(frame: mapBoxWrapper.bounds, styleURL: NSURL(string:"dark-v7.json"))
        mapView = Mapbox.configure(mapView)
        // set the map's center coordinate
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(appleMap.userLocation.coordinate,
            zoomLevel: 12, animated: true)
        mapBoxWrapper.addSubview(mapView)
   }

}
```

I want to also use a map ID instead of a URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map ID's are for raster map tile images and not GL. You want to do one of two things:

1. Actually use a raster map: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-ios/examples/raster-styles/
2. Stay tuned when we will allow complete customization of *vector* styles and export of a style ID to apply to your `MGLMapView`. Watch the [blog](http://mapbox.com/blog).